# Nikon lens have weird sound when autofocusing after dropping

Tags: lens, nikon

Today I dropped my Nikon D50 with AF-S 35mm from about 0.5m high to wooden floor. Lens landed first. Everything seems to be fine except that the lens is making disquieting sounds when autofocusing. It's a bit like scratching and rubbing. Focusing manually works fine.

I also tried some other lens but they all works: no sounds. I'm a bit worried since the motor might be broken.

Is it serious? Can I fix it myself? Or should I visit a repair shop?

Comment: You can also wonder if you haven't bent the body around the mount which would cause all your lens to be misaligned.

Comment: There is no way we could give you an answer to that without more detail. Does the AF still work and are images sharp. If yes, it is obviously not that serious.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @xenoid I'm sure the mount is fine since other lens works well. However I feel extra friction when mounting the 35/1.8 so the lens itself might have been misaligned.

Comment: A bent mount wouldn't prevent other lenses from working, but you could have off-center focus problems (all your lens would behave a bit like tilt lenses)

Answer (score 2):

The 35/1.8 DX lens? It is almost certainly "serious," and it is extremely unlikely you can fix it yourself.
It is also not cost effective having it repaired... you can get a used one in excellent condition [from a reputable source](https://www.keh.com/nikon-nikkor-35mm-f-1-8g-af-s-dx-wide-angle-lens.html?aid=209484-190229&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=Nikon&utm_term=209484-190229&gclid=CjwKCAjwv4SaBhBPEiwA9YzZvOCpC_Xwqb8JVuIwaJOxpmhUlKf3Y-Ic6GGi4C75rC---0nfCiCKqBoCIaAQAvD_BwE) for under $100; or brand new for under $200

If it is the G-ED version, then it's a little closer and the repair might cost less than replacing it.